An artist kills and uses evidence from the scene in his paintings
All I can remember about this movie is that an art student struggles to find a medium, then he murders woman and paints them as they die (or their face in death). The police think it's a serial killer and starts to search. The man is then caught as he puts the one woman's license card in one of the paintings. I can't remember when the film was made, but was on television around 2010. 

Sounds very much like an episode of Tales from the Crypt.

It sounds rather a lot like the plot from Art School Confidential. Came out in '06.
Paraphrased from Wikipedia's plot synopsis:

The community has been wracked by a serial killer, the Strathmore Strangler, who has confounded the police. As Jerome slowly loses his idealism at art school, he finds himself in competition with a strange newcomer.
In a wild attempt to win a prestigious art competition, Jerome asks for, and gets, Jimmy's paintings, all of which are of the Strangler's victims. The police arrest Jerome as the Strangler (who in fact was Jimmy)

Plus some screenshots of the paintings in question:


